# Unique Attributes of Product Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Maybe my question is unclear, but I will try anyway:

Are there some known interesting attributes that applyed only to a space which is a product space of many spaces?

Attributes $ P $ like: If $(X,T)$ is a topological space that satistify $ P $, than there exists $ (Y_\alpha, T_\alpha) $ such that $ X $ is the product of the $ Y_\alpha $?

At least two of $ Y_\alpha $ have to include more than one point.

I am looking for a suprising such attributes. Thanks!

Comment: A classic result related with your question: every totally disconnected compact metric space is homeomorphic to a *subset* of a countable product of discrete spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ has finitely many ($n \ge 2$) connected components $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ that are all mutually homeomorphic. Then $X \simeq C_1 \times D(n)$, where $D(n)$ is a discrete space on $n$ points.

The same can be done for a locally connected space $X$ with any number of mutually homeomorphic non-singleton components.

If $X$ is discrete or indiscrete we can write it as a product iff it is finite and its size is composite or $X$ is infinite.

If a space is a product, it will have some properties: (if such an $X$ is connected then $X\setminus\{p\}$ is also connected, i.e. $X$ has no cutpoints) but I feel these are far from sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, since every topological space is homeomorphic to itself cross the one point topology.

Comment: Thanks, it's seem too trivial in my setting. I will change it to pass the trivial cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if that's really an answer, but I found that there is a related study about spaces which are, according the wikipedia, "locally product spaces" (called Fiber bundle)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle